# Scipy.optimize.minimize is not changing the parametters at all or is giving me garbage

Tags: optimization, scipy, constraints, bounds

I have a multivariate bounded optimization problem optimization problem.  A simplified version is below.  When I run the code, I am getting a very poor results.  I compared this to the optimizer in Excel and the poor fit is confirmed.  In my real problem, I cannot use Excel's solver because each iteration involves running a subroutine, which Excel cannot do with Solver.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
def stressfunc(a, b, c, d, e, f, x):
#generic function for elasticity and yield    
    from numpy import exp
    stress = a * (1.0 + b * exp(c * x)) / (1.0 + x) ** d + e * x + f
    return stress
#----------------------------------------------------------------------    
def test_function(params,x):
    a=params[1]
    b=params[2]
    c=params[3]
    d=params[4]    
    e=params[5]
    f=params[6]
#-----------------
#target values   
    abar=2.0
    bbar=-1.0
    cbar=-2.0
    dbar=-30.0
    ebar=300.0
    fbar=20.0
#----------------- 
    sumy=0.0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y=stressfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,x[i])
        ybar=stressfunc(abar,bbar,cbar,dbar,ebar,f,x[i])
        sumy=sumy+(y-ybar)**2
    return sumy
#----------------------------------------------------------------------    
def param_constraint(params):
#inequality constraint > 0
    a=params[1]
    b=params[2]
    f=params[6]
    return f-a*(1.0+b) 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------   
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
#-----------------  
test_bounds=((0.0,0.0),(0.0,100.0),(-10.0,10.0),(-10000.0,0.0),(-200.0,200.0),(-500.0,5000.0),(-500.0,500.0))
#-----------------  
cons=({'type': 'ineq','fun':param_constraint})
#-----------------  
params=np.zeros(7)
params[1]=1.0
params[2]=-2.1
params[3]=-1.0
params[4]=-2.00
params[5]=-100.0
params[6]=250.0
#-----------------  
t=np.zeros(101)
for i in range(1,101):
    t[i]=t[i-1]+0.05
#-----------------  
result=scipy.optimize.minimize(test_function,params,args=t,method='SLSQP',bounds=test_bounds,constraints=cons,options={'maxiter': 5000})
result=scipy.optimize.minimize(test_function,result.x,args=t,method='SLSQP',bounds=test_bounds,constraints=cons,options={'maxiter': 5000})
print(result)
```

UPDATE:

I changed the objective function per the normal f(*args) format.  But it gave me the eXACT same answer.

```
def test_function(params,*argv):
    import numpy
    a=params[1]
    b=params[2]
    c=params[3]
    d=params[4]    
    e=params[5]
    f=params[6]
#-----------------
#target values   
    abar=2.0
    bbar=-1.0
    cbar=-2.0
    dbar=-30.0
    ebar=300.0
    fbar=20.0
#----------------- 
    t=argv[0]
    for i in range(len(t)):
        y=stressfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,t[i])
        ybar=stressfunc(abar,bbar,cbar,dbar,ebar,f,t[i])
    sumy=np.sum((y-ybar)**2)
    return sumy
```

[Parameters and Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjWkc.jpg)

Comment: The objective function must be `fun(x, *args) -> float`. Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: Thx.  I tried that but it gave me the exact same answer.  sigh......ANything else you can think of would be much appreciated.